# How can I print on 11x17 paper by specifying the printer tray in the postscript file?

Tags: rhel, printer, postscript

This is a unix question as it may involve changing settings on the unix printer driver, or getting the right printer driver in the first place.

Unix: RHEL 5.1 (Tikanga)
Printer hardware: Kyocera Taskalfa 5551ci

We can print from Linux on 8.5x11 paper just fine, but that's probably because the 8.5x11 paper tray is the default tray. When I create a PS file that selects the printer tray, the print out does not come out at all, in fact the print job never appears in the printer hardware queue in the first place.

We got a list of valid tray names from the printer via the `lpoption` command. When I use one of the trays in the PS file the printer still doesn't print a thing, no job appears in the printer hardware queue, and the printer doesn't even turn on like it's warming up.

1. What driver should we get for our printer? The PS driver? Something else?
2. On the printer hardware, what settings should we look for and change?

Thank you.

Comment: What `PPD` file is being used for the printer? For CUPS, these usually live under `/etc/cups/ppd` and should be referenced from the printer entry in `/etc/cups/printers.conf`.

Comment: Is the printer on the network? Add the output of `loptions` to your Post. How did you specify the tray in your PostScript file? Some printers allow you to connect for control via an `http://` and the printer name in your browser, and so may provide access to a log of jobs and errors.